# Hi, I am a beginner coder and when using arcade I found this error with a simple program

Tags: python, arcade

```
 import arcade
    
    class MyGamewindow(arcade.Window):
        def __init__(self, width,height,title):
            super().__init__(width,height,title)
            self.set_location(400,200)
MyGamewindow(800, 400, 'xy')
arcade.run()
```

This is my error

```
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 364, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I checked the files and there seems to be no problem
Please help regarding this, not familiar with advanced fixes or stuff provided in other solutions

Comment: The traceback is truncated; we can't see which "the specified module" is.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the command `conda install arcade` from command prompt then run the program.
If it works ok else run the command `pip install arcade`.

Comment: Hi. thanks for replying, done both and doesnt work

Comment: can you tell what output you get on running these commands

Comment: Can you create a conda virtual environment and activate it and install the packages then. It should work.

Comment: wow it worked. Thank you so so much. Really nice to see the community here :)